# Ruby now can be unit test done on print method

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

How can be unit test done on the following printing method `call get_list()`?

With `assert_equal("["apple", "orange", "pear"]",@list.get_list())` the result is nil.

```
@list = ["apple", "orange", "pear"] 

def get_list()
   i = 0
   while (i < list.size())
      puts list[i]
      i = i + 1
   end
end
```

Please can somebody give me tip please

Comment: In your method I think you meant to use `@list` instead of `list`

Comment: A function `get_list` should return a list. A printing method should be called `print_list`. Your assertion has a syntax error (`"["apple", "orange", "pear"]"` makes no sense. Your `get_list` prints `"apple\norange\npear\n"` - What do you want to _print_ or to be tested really?)

Answer (score 1):

[Kernel#puts](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) always returns nil. You probably want to use [Kernel#p](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) instead. For example:

```
@list = %w[apple orange pear]
def get_list
  @list.each { |item| p item }
end
```

Depending on what you think #get_list should return, you may need to refactor the method further. Just make sure you return something other than nil, either explicitly or implicitly.